# error: MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

**I tried using `const course ={....}` instead of `const course = new course({...})` and also removing the `_id` from it, but to no avail. I tried taking hints by using `logger` but that too didnt depict my issue.**

**course.js**

```
 router.put(
    "/:id",
    (req, res, next) => {
        
        const course = new Course({
            _id: req.body.id,
            coursename: req.body.coursename,
            duration: req.body.duration,
            strength: req.body.strength
        });
        logger.trace('Details: ', course);
        logger.trace(req.body);
        Course.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, course).then(result => {
            logger.trace('Result: ', result);
            if (result.nModified > 0) {
                res.status(200).json({ message: "Update successful!" });
            }
            else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: "Access Denied!" });
            }

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err);
        });
    }
);
```

**Here's the `updatePosts()` function of `course.service.ts` file that I use for linking with backend for course**

```
    updatePosts(id: string, coursename: string, duration: string, strength: number) {
    let CData: courseData | FormData;
    
    CData = new FormData();
    CData.append("id", id);
    CData.append("coursename", coursename);
    CData.append("duration", duration);
    CData.append("strength", strength.toString());
    
    this.http
      .put("http://localhost:3300/api/admin/courses/" + id, CData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const updatedCourses = [...this.courses];
        const oldPostIndex = updatedCourses.findIndex(p => p.id === id);
        const post: courseData = {
          id: id,
          coursename: coursename,
          duration: duration,
          strength: strength
        };
        updatedCourses[oldPostIndex] = post;
        this.courses = updatedCourses;
        this.coursesUpdated.next([...this.courses]);
        
        // this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }
```

[image: this is the error that I get]

Comment: Do you receive id from req.body.id  ?

Comment: Do `req.body.id` and `req.params.id` have exactly the same value?

Comment: @AshwinR No, the id from req.body.id says undefined, but the id displayed using course shows the id as above

Comment: @Joe No, req.params.id is not getting accessed only.